# Clarifying Shacl sh:qualifiedValueShape

Tags: shacl

The definition of sh:qualifiedValueShape state:

> The shape that the specified number of value nodes needs to conform to. The values of sh:qualifiedValueShape in a shape must be well-formed shapes. Node shapes cannot have any value for sh:qualifiedValueShape. This is a mandatory parameter of sh:QualifiedMinCountConstraintComponent and sh:QualifiedMaxCountConstraintComponent.

Then we have the following examples

```
ex:QualifiedValueShapeExampleShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetNode ex:QualifiedValueShapeExampleValidResource ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path ex:parent ;
        sh:minCount 2 ;
        sh:maxCount 2 ;
        sh:qualifiedValueShape [
            sh:path ex:gender ;
            sh:hasValue ex:female ;
        ] ;
        sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
    ] .
```

```
ex:HandShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass ex:Hand ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path ex:digit ;
        sh:maxCount 5 ;
    ] ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path ex:digit ;
        sh:qualifiedValueShape [ sh:class ex:Thumb ] ;
        sh:qualifiedValueShapesDisjoint true ;
        sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
        sh:qualifiedMaxCount 1 ;
    ] ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path ex:digit ;
        sh:qualifiedValueShape [ sh:class ex:Finger ] ;
        sh:qualifiedValueShapesDisjoint true ;
        sh:qualifiedMinCount 4 ;
        sh:qualifiedMaxCount 4 ;
    ] .
```

Although I understand both example well, what i don't get, is how the second example technically match the specification. I'm more specically pointing at

```
sh:qualifiedValueShape [ sh:class ex:Finger ]
```

That is. While in

```
sh:qualifiedValueShape [
            sh:path ex:gender ;
            sh:hasValue ex:female ;
        ] ;
```

we can see that the blank node is a **property shape**, I have no idea what kind of shape the blank node in

```
sh:qualifiedValueShape [ sh:class ex:Finger ]
```

does actually represents.

Is there something implicit that i do not see here ? **sh:class** is used in property shape, so what is the actual path here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ sh:class ex:Finger ] constraint is an implicit Node Shape (because it has no sh:path triple). Here it means that four of the values of ex:digit must conform to the specified shape, i.e. they must be instances of ex:Finger. Node shapes get evaluated against the nodes directly, and at that stage the path has already been evaluated by the surrounding property shape.